# SymPy: Limit symbol/variable to interval

Tags: range, intervals, solver, sympy

Using SymPy, is it possible to limit the possible values of a symbol/variable to a certain range? I now I can set some properties while defining symbols, like `positive=True`, but I need more control, i.e. I need to set it to be in the interval [0,1]. This assumption should then be used for solving, simplifying etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify the bounds as inequalities such as `x >= lb` and `x <= ub`, for example:

```
from sympy.solvers import solve
from sympy import Symbol
x = Symbol('x')
solve([x >= 0.5, x <= 3, x**2 - 1], x)
```

Here we search for a solution of equation `x**2 == 1` such that `x` is in the interval `[0.5, 3]`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. However, I need the same for multiple variables at the same time, which raises NotImplementedError: only univariate inequalities are supported. Too bad...

Answer (score 7):

As for simplification, you want `refine`. Unfortunately, it doesn't yet support using inequality syntax, so you'll have to use `Q.positive` or `Q.negative` (or `Q.nonpositive` or `Q.nonnegative` for non-strict inequalities). The most common simplification that it handles is `sqrt(x**2) = x` if `x >= 0`.

```
>>> refine(sqrt((x - 1)**2), Q.positive(x - 1))
x - 1
>>> refine(sqrt((x - 1)**2), Q.positive(x))
Abs(x - 1)
```

Note in the second case you still get a simpler answer because it at least knows that `x - 1` is real under the given assumptions.

If your assumptions are as simple as "`x` is positive" or "`x` is negative", the best chance for success is to define it on the Symbol itself, like

```
>>> Symbol('x', positive=True)
>>> sqrt(x**2)
x
```

Answer (score 5):

Now you can use `solveset`

`In [3]: solveset(x**2 - 1, x, Interval(0.5, 3))
Out[3]: {1}`

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Does that work for multiple variables and inequalities as well?

Answer (score 2):

In sympy 1.1.1 I found that this works. It can be easily adapted to your case.

```
>>> x = Symbol('x', domain=S.Reals)
>>> solve_domain = And(0 <= x, x < 2*pi).as_set()
>>> solve_domain
[0, 2⋅π)
# solve_domain must be evaluated before solveset call
>>> solveset(sin(x), x, solve_domain)
{0, π}
```

I don't know why things fall apart if you don't evaluate solve_domain before calling solveset, but it's easy to work around once you know.