# SymPy: Limit symbol/variable to interval – again

Tags: range, intervals, sympy, simplify

This is very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553652/sympy-limit-symbol-variable-to-interval) and I wonder whether something has happened in the last few years along these lines. I have version 1.0rc1.

In particular, having a symbol `epsilon` that represents an angle in the interval [0,π/2], I would like

```
asin(sin(epsilon))
```

to be `epsilon`, and

```
Abs(cos(epsilon))
```

to be `cos(epsilon)`. I suppose if sympy knew about the interval of `epsilon`, it would be able to do such simplifications.

Comment: SymPy isn't really able to make simplifications based on symbols being in an interval at this point in time. Your best bet is to use `replace` to replace expressions with simpler forms that you know are correct.

Comment: Thanks, I’ll try to live with that.